# Parsing an XML with Xpath in PHP

Tags: php, xml, parsing, xpath

Consider the following code :

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($file);

$xmlPath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$arrNodes = $xmlPath->query('*/item');
foreach($arrNodes as $item){
//missing code
}
```

The $file is an xml and each item has a title and a description.
How can I display them (title and description)?

```
$file = "<item>
   <title>test_title</title>
   <desc>test</desc>
</item>";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your item looks like this:

```
<item>
    <title>foo</title>
    <description>frob</description>    
</item>
```

You could use [`getElementsByTagName()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domelement.getelementsbytagname.php) and [`nodeValue`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.nodevalue):

```
foreach($arrNodes as $item){
    print $item->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue;
}
```

---

Are `title` and `description` attributes? E. g. does an item look like this:

```
<item title="foo" description="frob" />
```

If so, you could just use [`getAttribute()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domelement.getattribute.php):

```
...
foreach($arrNodes as $item){
    print $item->getAttribute('title');
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I suggest using php's `simplexml`, with that, you still get `xpath` functionality, but with easier approach, for example you would access attributes like this:

```
$name = $item['name'];
```

Here's an example:

xmlfile.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xml>
    <items>
        <item title="Hello World" description="Hellowing the world.." />
        <item title="Hello People" description="greeting people.." />
    </items>
</xml>
```

do.php:

```
<?php
$xml_str = file_get_contents('xmlfile.xml');
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml_str);
$items = $xml->xpath('*/item');

foreach($items as $item) {
    echo $item['title'], ': ', $item['description'], "\n";
}
```

Comment: Ok , but is xpath that limited ?

Comment: @daniphp, how do you mean, are you asking about xpath query capabilities in general or about simplexml's limitations?

Answer (score 0):

The right XPath expression should be:

```
/*/item/title | /*/item/desc
```

Or

```
/*/item/*[self::title or self::desc]
```

This is evaluate to a node set with `title` and `desc` element in document order