# Return a php xpath answer with SOAP

Tags: php, xml, exception, soap, xpath

I m trying to return an xpath answer to a soap client (i am using an xml file as database).
The method works fine when it's called on the server side, unfortunatelly, the client always  get an annoying " looks like we got no XML document " error, with this kind of
[xml answer](http://pastebin.com/hnmRn5Ja):

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="urn://localhost/projet/srv" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ns2="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<ns1:getTypesVehiculeResponse>
<return SOAP-ENC:arrayType="SOAP-ENC:Struct[4]" xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array">
<item xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Struct">
<@attributes xsi:type="ns2:Map">
<item>
<key xsi:type="xsd:string">id</key>
<value xsi:type="xsd:string">0</value>
</item>
...
</return>
</ns1:getTypesVehiculeResponse>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Should I use another way to send my XML database answers than directly return xpath answer?

Comment: PHP's [SoapClient](http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php) should give you an array of data - why do you need xpath? If you're trying to parse HTML, why not just retrieve it with cURL or `file_get_contents()`?

Comment: I am using xpath to query the xml file that is acting like a database (on the server side).

Comment: Okay, but I'm saying you may not need to. Can you give an example of what xpath query you're trying to use?

Comment: For the moment i only use simple queries like : /bdd/typevehicules/* to retrieve all child elements of a category, but in the future i would like to be able to filter the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SoapClient` should eliminate the need for xpath querying since it already parses the SOAP XML, but if you still want to use xpath, you can try using `simplexml` as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3630000/633406). If you have an issue with namespaces, [try this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3864690/633406)